# Ways to fetch more dimensions and large data from Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

As per Google Analytics (GA APV4) docs,there’s a limit to the number of dimensions we can see side-by-side: two dimensions is usually their limit in the interface (dashboard), five in custom reports, and the API allows for nine dimensions.

But my requirement where I have 40+ Custom Dimensions and 20+ Metrics, all need to be fetched within one API report request.

I know GA API v4 won't support this requirement, but is there any one who have implemented such scenario or any other solutions on this?

Comment: For a GA360 account there is always BigQuery. For a standard account there is no proper solution.

Comment: @EikePierstorff   Thanks ,Yes, We have GA360 account.will look into BigQuery. I will be getting more than 2-3M hits , will it easier to pull such large data with 60-70 columns in  report

Answer (score 3):

[Create a BigQuery project to export your Google Analytics data](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437618?hl=en).

The available dimensions are [described in the export schema](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en).

Use SQL to retrieve your dimensions/metrics combo. If you need visualization export your query to a table and connect to Google data studio. Note that the BigQuery UI is pretty crude - usually you would create reports via the BigQuery API rather than using the web interface.

While [BigQuery isn't free](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing) the cost is pretty much negligible (especially since a credit for BigQuery usage is included in the GA360 fee), at least if you limit queries to the actually necessary data (if you do a lot of "select *" things might get a tad more expensive).

Another advantage are that there are no API limits for data retrieval. It would probably not even be possible to export 3mio hits with custom dimensions via the reporting API. For BigQuery selecting 3mio rows is trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much for the support!